# Could sharing ifconfig information publicly be dangerous?

Tags: linux, ifconfig

Is there any dangers in sharing my ifconfig information from Linux publicly?

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on the [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your ip address is IPv4 and it's private (192.168.X, 127.x, 172.17.x, 10.x) you have no risk (if the risk for you is given by the fact that it's possibile to reach you by the internet).

If you have a IPv6 address you'll have to pay attention because it will probably be visible by the internet.

Then, it's possible to catch your hardware address (mac address), but this is not dangerous since it's not routable.

I cannot see any other risk here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's a little risk, but a number of factors would have to come into play for it to be an issue.  The main risk I see is if someone gained access internally to your network.  They'd then have your internal IP (nothing a quick nmap scan couldn't find) and your MAC address (could be useful for attacking a wireless network or perhaps a Man-in-the-middle attack).